What circuitry is needed to control several concurrent USB-C ports in device (UFP) mode?
I would like to design a device which can connect via USB-C to several different hosts simultaneously, acting as a device for all of them concurrently. For example, I want my device to show up as a mass storage device on several computers at once. Note that a typical USB hub is not what I want: If I understand correctly, it will add more host-mode (DFP) ports. What I want is to add more device-mode (UFP) ports.
Ideally, I would like to use something like a Raspberry Pi Compute Module, or other SoM capable of running Linux, to simplify the "compute" capabilities of this device.
My question is: What is the simplest circuitry I can add to an off-the-shelf SoM to give it the capability to act as a USB device for multiple different hosts simultaneously? Is this capability something that needs to be built-in to a microcontroller or SoM at a very low level, or is there something akin to a USB hub, but for device mode?

How will your device handle simultaneous data access--what if one computer is writing to the device while another is trying to read the same data? There's a reason this isn't a standard product--it causes problems.

That's why I'm asking the question: I can figure out the software later (or ask on a different stack exchange :) ), but if there's a particular concern you have about hardware that renders this impossible or difficult, could you please elaborate?

Unrelated to hardware suggestions, one thing you could consider is USB port virtualization over a network. For example, if you plug a flash drive into one system, you could essentially broadcast that device to the network and allow other hosts to access that flash drive without necessarily setting up a sophisticated SAN infrastructure. Otherwise, hardware suggestions would be challenging because you'd likely have to bifurcate data signals which is rather convoluted.

You simply need a module with enough UFP (device) ports. However the big picture is missing, why? Would all hosts see the a separate mass storage device data or the same data? In other words, how would it even work if two computers want to write a file with data and they don't know some other computer is also accessing the very same sectors/blocks of data?


What is the simplest circuitry I can add to an off-the-shelf SoM to give it the capability to act as a USB device for multiple different hosts simultaneously?

USB to Ethernet.
Your driver will then setup and configure the network card with a network share. Accessible on your Raspberry PI CM host module.
You can write your own driver making it as complex as you want. USB over Ethernet is a thing. But it's not easy.


acting as a device for all of them concurrently.

You will then need a separate device state machine for each host connection. So for \$N\$ hosts, you'll need  \$N\$ independent implementations of all the USB device logic.
That doesn't include the logic necessary to actually "logically" make your USB device work with multiple hosts, which might be hard, very much depending on what your device does.

For example, I want my device to show up as a mass storage device on several computers at once.

Unless you're a read-only device, that's a terrible idea, because host computers cache accesses, especially write accesses, and that means that your device can't know what computer A has changed about some blocks on your storage device when B asks for them. Even so, there's no common file system designed for devices that get accessed concurrently. This simply doesn't work, usual file systems have no possibility to be used by multiple parties at once.
Build something else. A logical pattern \$N\$ independent USB network card implementations, e.g. in an FPGA, which also emulates a network and attaches a CPU with its own network interface to that network, to serve files. The idea here is that you're really communicating data, if you share it between multiple hosts, not just store it.

Ideally, I would like to use something like a Raspberry Pi Compute Module, or other SoM capable of running Linux, to simplify the "compute" capabilities of this device.

The RPi is especially spartanic in that respect, but typical Linux SoM that you might be able to buy generally rarely offer more than \$N=2\$ functional units to implement USB state machines.

My question is: What is the simplest circuitry I can add to an off-the-shelf SoM to give it the capability to act as a USB device for multiple different hosts simultaneously?

None such circuitry can exist, so none does exist. It's a problem that can't be solved as an external "add on".

Is this capability something that needs to be built-in to a microcontroller or SoM at a very low level, or is there something akin to a USB hub, but for device mode?

No such "reverse hub" can exist; that's simply not how USB was designed.
You're really looking for a network of devices. You need different protocol approaches than what USB offers. Hence, you'll have to go a "detour" by attaching your devices to something that can do internetworking. Ethernet or similar.
